# Changeing the ID of a MVC Router from an integer to a string in vb.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, routes

i'm looking at some pages, and i've noticed that by default for ID in the routing for controller/action/ID is an integer and not a string.

How can I change it so it is a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purely by creating an action like this:

```
Public Function MyAction(ByVal id as String) as ActionResult
```

The framework converts the url `MyController/MyAction/SomeId` for you. Normally it would convert the last section into an integer as that is how your method is defined, there's nothing to stop you from saying that it is a string and so no conversion is needed.